# If $z=4+i \sqrt{7}$ then find the value of $z^3 -4z^2 -9z + 91$.

Tags: complex-numbers

So i was learning complex numbers and i came across this problem. In the solution they have made $z-4=i\sqrt{7}$ and then they squared the above equation resulting in $z^2 -8z+16=-7$ then they proceeded by sending $-7$ to the LHS resulting in $z^2 -8z+23=0$.

They then divided the original cubic term by the resulting equation from the above steps to get answer as $-1$. 
I did not understand why did they do it and how they got $-1$. 
 The final equation looked like this: 
$z^3 -4z^2 -9z + 91=(z^2 -8z+23)(z+4)-1=-1$.

I personally think they used the $x=nq+r$ where $x$ is divided by $n$ resulting in $q$ as the quotient and $r$ as the remainder. 
 If so then can all the problems like this be solved in the same manner?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What don't you understand? The result of the division?

Comment: I don't understand the method being used. Like is it similar as dividing i^n by i^4 to find the actual value of i^n. Can that same concept even be used in the a complex number equation. In general i need someone to explain it to me like why and what is going on.

Comment: The given $z$ satisfy a second order equation with rational coefficients ($z^2 = Az + B$ for some rational numbers $A,B$). This means that any polynomial expression with rational coefficients can be reduced to the form $Cz+D$ with $C,D$ rational. The way to do this is by polynomial division as you point out. In this particular case $C$ turns out to be $0$ and $D=-1$ so you get the simple answer $-1$.

Comment: Thankyou sir. Also can i solve similar problems in this way?

Comment: See the answer below, it explains it well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You surely get $(z-4)^2=-7$, which indeed expands to $z^2-8z+23=0$.

Then you can do the long division of $z^3-4z^2-9z+91$ by $z^2-8z+23$, which yields a quotient $z+4$ and remainder $-1$; therefore, for *any* value of $z$, you have
$$
z^3-4z^2-9z+91=(z^2-8z+23)(z+4)-1
$$
If you substitute the given $z$, then you get
$$
0(4+i\sqrt{7}+4)-1=-1
$$

Yes, problems of this kind can be treated in this way; if $w$ is any complex number and $g(z)$ is a polynomial such that $g(w)=0$, then for every polynomial $f(z)$ one has
$$
f(z)=q(z)g(z)+r(z)
$$
where the degree of $r$ is less than the degree of $g$, so
$$
f(w)=q(w)g(w)+r(w)=r(w)
$$
and the computation of $r(w)$ is easier.

Comment: Thank you sir. 

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, note:
$$z-4=i\sqrt7 \iff z-3=1+i\sqrt7 \iff z+3=7+i\sqrt7.$$
You can replace step-by-step:
$$\begin{align}z^3 -4z^2 -9z + 91=&z^2(z-4)-9(z-4)+55=\\
=&(z+3)(z-3)(z-4)+55=\\
=&(i\sqrt7+7)(1+i\sqrt7)(i\sqrt7)+55=\\
=&(i\sqrt7+7)(i\sqrt7-7)+55=\\
=&-7-49+55=\\
=&-1.\end{align}$$